# Compare string date to current long time

Tags: java, android

A search API is returning date in `String` format,I want to compare that date with current date and do something. I created a date object and parsed it but still getting error when I do the compare.

```
Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
long dateNow = currentDate.getTimeInMillis();

String eventDate = meta.getString("startDate"); //This is the string API returns

SimpleDateFormat formatter  = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss.SSS");
Date date = formatter.parse(eventDate);
long modifiedDate= date.getTime();

if (dateNow.compareTo(modifiedDate)>0) {
    //Do Something
}
```

**Error I get is :**

```
Cannot invoke compareTo(long) on the primitive type long
```

Thanks.

Comment: What's the ERROR, post your logcat

Comment: Can you please post details about the error? Are you getting compilation error or runtime exception?

Comment: Is there a reason you're going to the trouble of converting to `long`s instead of just using the `before` and `after` methods defined by `java.util.Date`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When comparing primitive `long`s just use a vanilla comparison operator:

```
dateNow > modifiedDate
```

This is not recommended, but if you want to use `compareTo`, first convert to `Long`:

```
Long.valueOf(dateNow).compareTo(Long.valueOf(modifiedDate)) > 0
```

Comment: Yes, just because you *can* do something doesn't mean you should. And yes, I didn't downvote... after all, you warned.

Answer (score 1):

compareTo method is part of wrapper classes, long is primitive datatype - you cannot call method on primitive datatype. Either change long to Long or compare long directly like dateNow > modifiedDate

Answer (score 1):

`long` is a primitive type, which means it is not an object and doesn't have basic methods like `compareTo`, etc. You can perform mathematical operations to compare them though:

```
if (dateNow - modifiedDate > 0) /* dateNow is later than modifiedDate */
```

Another solution is using `Long` (capital L) which *is* an object. Then you can use `compareTo`, etc.

Answer (score -2):

`compareTo` is a method. It is not defined for the primitive type `long`. It *is* defined for the Date class.

```
Date dateNow = currentDate.getTime(); // instead of getTimeInMillis()
...
if (dateNow.compareTo(date)) { // this will now work
```

If they're both Date objects, you can do `dateNow.before(date)` which makes much more sense semantically.

Alternatively, you can use the > and < operators and do `dateNow < modifiedDate` if you leave `dateNow` as a long.

Comment: Primitives do not descend from `Object` type, therefore they aren't your typical objects (academic, I know). One of the most basic consequences is that they don't have their own methods. Because `dateNow` is of the primitive type `long`, that code couldn't possibly even compile... and when you suggest code here on this site, people are very sensitive in order to require your code to, at the very least, not have blatant bugs on them like that... when in doubt, don't rush just to try to get the upvotes and the green ticks.

Comment: @DavidCesarino- in the code above, I mentioned that if the OP changed the dateNow to be a *Date* object, s/he could use the compareTo method? It is not a long anymore. The Calendar getTime() returns Date, not long. (You may have not refreshed; I changed the post 10 minutes back when I realized that the OP had set dateNow as a long not a Date.)

Comment: The downvotes were for your original, unedited answer (as can be seen in the review history). You need to pass the same data type as you said, but the "fix" as you told doesn't apply because your code still assumed a `long` ("*The simplest fix would be simply to compare to date instead:*"). Please perform a minor edit in your answer and I'll be glad to remove mine. Unfortunately, right now I can't because the vote is locked.